# Erro em programa de Python

Tags: python-3.x

Boa tarde

Alguém me pode explicar porque é que o meu codigo nao dá o resultado pedido e o que posso fazer para obter a solução pedida?

Aparece o erro:
total = round(soma,NDec[k])TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Implemente uma função com três parâmetros, que, para um dado ângulo em graus (primeiro parâmetro), um vetor `N` (segundo parâmetro), com valores crescentes do numero de termos da serie a usar, calcula e retorna um vetor com o valor da aproximação da função co-seno obtida com cada um dos `Ni` termos da serie de Taylor, para o angulo dado.

O número de casas decimais a usar no resultado para cada numero de termos é dado pelo vetor `NDec` (terceiro parâmetro), com o índice `i` do vetor indicando o numero de casas decimais a apresentar para o numero de termos definido no índice `i` do vetor `N`. O vetor `N` não deve ser modificado pela função.

```
import math
def taylor(ang,N,NDec):
ang_rad = math.radians(ang)
res = []
soma = 0
for i in range(len(N)): 
    for k in range(len(NDec)):
        for j in range(N[i]):
            aprox_cos = (-1)**j/(math.factorial(2*j)) * ang_rad**(2*j)
            soma = soma + aprox_cos
        total = round(soma,NDec[k])
    res.append(total)
return res
```

Eu utilizei na consola

`ang = 180`

`N=[3, 4, 6, 10, 20]`

`NDec=[4, 6, 8, 10, 10]`

A solução é:

```
[0.1239, -1.211353, -1.0018291, -1.0000000035, -1.0]
```

Nota:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado a quem puder ajudar!

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que percebi, está faltando fechar um parêntesis na linha 7 e tem um colchete a mais na linha 9.

Acredito que corrigindo isso os erros não aparecem. Testei em um ambiente online de python.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, já corrigi isso e editei a pergunta, mas continua a não me dar o resultado pedido

Answer (score 0):

O problema é simples, você esta passando o angule em graus e a função deveria receber o angulo em radianos.

Eu refatorei um pouco o código porque não entendi aquela soma sua inicializada fora dos loops. Criei 2 métodos, um chamado taylor, que gera os resultados pra cada quantidade de elementos e uma compute_cos, que usa a série de taylor pra calcular pra 1 elemento.

```
def taylor(angle, vector, decimals):
    """Calcula a aproximacao do cosseno usando o metodo de Taylor

    Parameteres
    ----------
    angle : int angulo em graus
    vector : list com a quantidade de iteracoes a serem usadas pra aproximar o resultado
    decimals : quantidade de casas decimais do resultado
    """
    results = []

    for (i, element) in enumerate(vector):        
        _sum = compute_cos(element, angle)

        dec = decimals[i]
        result = round(_sum, dec)        
        results.append(result)

    return results


def compute_cos(iterations, angle):
    """Calcula aproximadamente o coseno de um angulo usando series de Taylor

    Parameters
    ----------
    iterations: quantidade de iteracoes na serie
    angle : int angulo a ser calculado o coseno em graus
    """
    _sum = 0

    angle = math.radians(angle)
    for n in range(iterations):
        fact = math.factorial(2 * n)
        dividendo = (-1) ** n
        cos = (dividendo / fact) * (angle ** (2 * n))
        _sum += cos

    return _sum
```

Rodando esses resultados, obtemos:

```
angle = 180
elements = [3, 4, 6, 10, 20] 
decimals = [4, 6, 8, 10, 10]
taylor(angle, elements, decimals)
>> [0.1239, -1.211353, -1.0018291, -1.0000000035, -1.0]
```

Que bate com o resultado que você espera.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta  mas podias explicar-me porque é que aparece o erro: total = round(soma,NDec[k])TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer , no codigo que editei?  eu no primeiro loop fiz com que i percorre todos os elementos de N , no segundo loop para dar as casas decimais que pretendo e no terceiro loop para percorrer os elementos de N[i] (estou a tentar so usar uma funcao)

Comment: As casas decimais não precisam de loop, o round só deve ser chamado uma vez pra cada elemento de N.

Comment: percebido, mas entao como é que fica o total?  Se fizer:  total = round(soma,NDec[i])
aparece-me o erro na mesma.

Comment: Nada indica no seu código pq desse erro. Esse erro deveria acontecer se NDec fosse uma lista de listas, mas não eh o que esta escrito no código que você postou.

Comment: Ja corri o programa assim e dá-me o resultado [0.1239, -1.087443, -2.08927202, -3.0892720247, -4.0892720247], ou seja so o primeiro valor esta correto. como resolvo isto?

Comment: Voce inicializou a soma dentro do primeiro for?

Comment: Ja meti a soma dentro do primeiro for e ja me deu o resultado correto. Faz sentido pois o que eu quero somar é os elementos de  "for j in range(N[i]):" Muito obrigado pela ajuda!